# Nested list with different style

Tags: html, css

HTML and Lists are on a new level for me with this question.
I am trying to create a nested list in HTML with related numbering and in the third level an alpha numbering type.

```css
body {
  padding-left: 100px;
}

ol {
    list-style-type: none;
    counter-reset: item;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

ol>li {
    display: table;
    counter-increment: item;
    margin-bottom: 0.6em;
}

ol>li:before {
    content: counters(item, ".",decimal-leading-zero) ". ";
    display: table-cell;
    padding-right: 0.6em;
}

li ol>li {
    margin: 0;
}

li ol>li:before {
    content: counters(item, ".",decimal-leading-zero) " ";
}
```

```html
<ol>
  <li>
    <ol>
      <li></li>
      <li></li>
      <li></li>
    </ol>
  </li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li>
    <ol>
      <li></li>
      <li>
        <ol>
          <li></li>
          <li></li>
          <li></li>
        </ol>
      </li>
    </ol>
  </li>
</ol>
```

Above is what I have. And that results in :

```
01.
  01.01
  01.02
  01.03
02.
03.
04.
  04.01
  04.02
      04.02.01
      04.02.02
      04.02.03
```

But I am looking for:

```
01.
  01.01
  01.02
  01.03
02.
03.
04.
  04.01
  04.02
        a.  ←
        b.  ←
        c.  ←
  04.03
```

Does anyone have a idea how to solve this?

I already tried numerise solution and searched the web. That is how I came to the above solution. But I could not find the third level lower-alpha type style solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please check below working code:

```css
ol {
        list-style-type: none;
        counter-reset: item;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
    }

    ol>li {
        display: block;
        counter-increment: item;
        margin-bottom: 0.6em;
        padding-left: 15px;
    }

    ol>li:before {
        content: counters(item, ".",decimal-leading-zero) ". ";
        display: table-cell;
        padding-right: 0.6em;
    }

    li ol>li {
        margin: 0;
    }

    li ol>li:before {
        content: counters(item, ".",decimal-leading-zero) " ";
    }
    
    ol>li>ol>li>ol
    {
    counter-reset: listStyle;
    }
    
        ol>li>ol>li>ol li{
  margin-left: 1em;
  counter-increment: listStyle;
}
        
        ol>li>ol>li>ol li::before {
  margin-right: 1em;
  content: counter(listStyle, lower-alpha);
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>

</head>

<body>

</body>
<ol>
    <li>
      <ol>
        <li></li>
        <li></li>
        <li></li>
      </ol>
    </li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li>
      <ol>
        <li></li>
        <li>
          <ol>
            <li></li>
            <li></li>
            <li></li>
          </ol>
        </li>
      </ol>
    </li>
  </ol>
</body>

</html>
```

**What is performed in the above code?**

Here, I have target the third level of `ol` where I have rest the counter and then re-initial in the `li` of third level `ol` and the used before css to get `lower-alpha`

Please let me know if you find any issue with the code

Comment: Can you point out which parts of the CSS you have changed?

Comment: Answer snippet updated, Please check it

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way would be to change your third level list items back into list items, hide the content and use the list style of lower-alpha:

```css
ol {
  list-style-type: none;
  counter-reset: item;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

ol>li {
  display: table;
  counter-increment: item;
  margin-bottom: 0.6em;
}

ol>li:before {
  content: counters(item, ".", decimal-leading-zero) ". ";
  display: table-cell;
  padding-right: 0.6em;
}

li ol>li {
  margin: 0;
}

li ol>li:before {
  content: counters(item, ".", decimal-leading-zero) " ";
}

/* below styles added, nothing else changed */

ol ol ol {
  list-style-type: lower-alpha;
}

ol ol ol li {
  display:list-item;
  margin-left: 1em;
}
ol ol ol li:before {
  content: none;
}
```

```html
<ol>
  <li>
    <ol>
      <li></li>
      <li></li>
      <li></li>
    </ol>
  </li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li>
    <ol>
      <li></li>
      <li>
        <ol>
          <li></li>
          <li></li>
          <li></li>
        </ol>
      </li>
    </ol>
  </li>
</ol>
```